# Reading userAccountControl in Windows2016 domain

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have this code that I use to read the "userAccountControl" active directory property and it works perfectly in our productive AD domain. I installed a Windows 2016 forest with subdomains in my test environment and this code no longer can read the "userAccountControl" attribute. I am domain admin in this domain and can see the attibute using "users and computers" and ADSI edit. The only account for which my code works is for my own. I guess there must be some security issue but can't find it. I am at a bit of a loss ... any any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What *does* happen when you try to read the attribute? An exception? Is it just blank? Also, how are you trying to read it? Can you show your code?

Comment: I just get a blank back. Sorry can't really show the code, cause it's part of a system that has been working for the last 15 years .... it seesm to be related to the AD security setting. If I put everyone "full control" on the accounts I can read the "useraccountcontrol" attribute. Also I can read any other attribute just not the "useraccountcontrol". Would have thought my domain admin rights would be enough permissions but I guess I am missing something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's odd. I haven't seen that before. Without seeing the code I don't have any ideas.